# What would gravity, breath, and human bodies be like near the heart of the Earth?

Tags: humans, gravity, atmosphere, mountains, hollow-earth

If humans lived on the inside of the earth's crust, what would happen if they climbed mountains? These mountains would stretch toward the burning center of the Earth. Would gravity get stronger the higher they climbed? Would they feel themselves pulled upward, away from the mountain? Would the air be thinner or thicker?

Comment: You're gonna need to add some more details about your hollow world; everyone has different ideas about their own, after all, and they strongly inform the range of valid answers. They're also all super soft science, so you should consider also mentioning what _sort_ of answers you're after. Science based? Soft scifi? Fantasy? As things stand, this is too many questions on a fairly fuzzy subject, and you risk have the question closed...

Comment: Haven't concretely decided on that yet. Still brainstorming. I was hoping to fill in my lacks of real scientific knowledge before I twisted anything.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info. Was directed here by a scientific friend when I couldn't find the information I was looking for elsewhere.

Comment: For future reference, I suggest reading your question titles before posting; this title is incomprehensible. Also, could you add some data? I am finding it hard to understand your question.

Comment: Re gravity, from Physics 101 the gravity from matter in a spherical shell outside of you is zero,  So they would only be affected by gravity from matter between them and the center.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the force of gravity would still pull them towards the centre of the Earth. So they would fall “upward” and away from the mountain. The force of gravity would also reduce towards the centre of the Earth and at the centre of the Earth there would be a net zero gravitational force. But by that time they would have hit the burning core at very high velocity.

However the force of gravity itself both on the surface and in your under world would be reduced because a lot of the Earths mass would have to be removed to allow your mountains to exist. They would presumably be pointing towards the centre of the Earth  in some form of atmosphere. The larger this inner atmosphere zone was the less the gravitational effects of planet Earth would be.

Note the question is not realistic such an inner world in not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think around the fourth? chapter of "The wandering Earth" by Cixin Liu, a really cool concept of an alien species that evolved within the center of a planet is introduced. I'd consider it required reading for this kind of story as those few chapters were very compelling.